# Does a packet taken from FFMPEG have absolue time information?

Tags: ffmpeg, timestamp

I'm creating a video player which works with an incomplete video file in which it has some empty(incomplete) sections filled with zeros.

For example, there's a video file which has section A, B, and C in sequence. A and C are complete and B is incomplete. And A section starts from file offset 0 and includes header information as well.

Now, I want to know a starting time of section C.

So I read packets from section A to section C entirely by using FFMPEG and it skipped section B which was what I wanted. But when I took presentation timestamp values from each packet while reading, I found it continuously increasing.

The problem is I want timestamps from section C to be increased by the amount of section B.

Even though section B is ignored, I want to know the actual time when I'm supposed to present section C.

I guess FFMPEG doesn't include absolute time information but calculates time to present a packet based on the last packet's time information which is relative. However, I assume there must be a way to find the absolute time information.